# Regular expression to search only websites names from random text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a regular expression that search and return only website names from a text.

e.g.

"Hello, the total description of deals are below:
mango: maangobar22.com
Total Deals : 0
apple: myapplesite22.com
Total Deals : 3
berrymine22.com
Total Deals : 0
We hope to hear from you soon"

I want to search all websites name and store them in different variable.

I created the following re but since I am new to RE, I am unable to think where to start.

```
import re
import sys

text = "Hello, the total description of deals are below: mango: maangobar22.com Total Deals : 0 apple: myapplesite22.com Total Deals : 3 berrymine22.com Total Deals : 0 We hope to hear from you soon"

num = re.match(r'+..com', "", text)
print('Phone Num : ', text)
a1 = num.group()
a2 = num.group(1)
a1 = num.group(2)
a2 = num.group(3)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: My 2-cents, just look it up in http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following for your example:

```
import re
websites = re.findall(r'(\S+[.]com)', text)
# ['maangobar22.com', 'myapplesite22.com', 'berrymine22.com']
```

Comment: but what about urls that don't end in '.com'?

Comment: @ClydeByrdIII Err, then add more TLDs ?